# What level of control is required for google cloud ml

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

When using google cloud ML to train models:

The official examples https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/census/tensorflowcore/trainer/task.py uses hooks, is_client, MonitoredTrainingSession and some other complexity.

Is this required for cloud ml or is using this example enough: https://github.com/amygdala/tensorflow-workshop/tree/master/workshop_sections/wide_n_deep?

The documentation is a bit limited in terms of best practices and optimisation, will GCP ML handle the client/worker mode or do we need to set devices e.g. `replica_device_setter` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CloudML Engine is largely agnostic to how you write your TensorFlow programs. You provide a Python program, and the service executes it for you, providing it with some [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/concepts/trainer-considerations#use_tf_config) you can use to perform distributed training (if necessary), e.g., task index, etc.

[census/tensorflowcore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/tensorflowcore/trainer) demonstrates how to do things with the "core" TensorFlow library -- how to do everything "from scratch", including using `replica_device_setters`, `MonitoredTrainingSessions`, etc.. This may be necessary sometimes for ultimate flexibility, but can be tedious.

Alongside the census/tensorflowcore example, you'll also see a sample called [census/estimator](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/estimator/trainer). This example is based on a higher level library, which unfortunately is in `contrib` and therefore does not yet have a fully stable API (expect lots of deprecation warnings, etc.). Expect it to stabilize in a future version of TensorFlow.

That particularly library (known as `Estimators`) is a higher level API that takes care of a lot of the dirty work for you. It will parse `TF_CONFIG` for you and setup the `replica_device_setter` as well as handle the `MonitoredTrainingSession` and necessary `Hook`s, while remaining fairly customizable.

This is the same library that the wide and deep example you pointed to is based on and they are fully supported on the service.